# Transfer uv maps operation error or Mesh not identical?

Tags: uv

here are two sets of mesh which looks identical, vert edge face count and even the vert index order are the same.
when use “transfer uv maps” from 2 to 1, 1 as active object. mesh 2’s uv is messed up (UV vert split up). vice versa.
if duplicate them and use transfer uv maps operator on their respective duplicates, ( after altering their UVs a little bit) the results work as expected.
how to make sure mesh 1 and 2 are identical? or in this case it is operator transfer uv maps error?
here is the file(http://uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1604139792&/UV map transfer.blend)
and screen grab:
[image: 1]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tested it from your file. Seems to work correctly.

Comment: take a closer look at the uv vert position, although the general shape is correct, it seems that each face is rotate a bit resulting not a seamless connect between faces. and many uv vert are not welded. Tested in clean install of 2.82a and various other versions 2,79. 2.90.

Comment: Seems to be totally identical here https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4F4J.jpg. Transfer UV Map is active to selected. Like all Ctrl+L operations. Not sure this is what you mean in the question.

Comment: from your screenshot, will you be able to make top left and bottom left meshes display the same texture using transfer uv maps? or have them all display the same?

Comment: I've transfered from original (left) to copy (right). Though, it work for the opposite too. Don't get how you have such results.

Comment: from top to bottom works too?

Comment: no, not from top to bottom

Comment: Should use mesh data transfert instead. Make sure meshes overlap as closely as possible before doing it.

Comment: that is why I ask why transfer uv maps does not work on those two identical mesh in this case.

Comment: The transfer operates but as it is. And as the meshes are different that gives the result you have. Use mesh *data* transfer, instead (with both meshes overlapping the closest possible). This one will use a projection cage to correct things (use "projected face interpolated" options). That will give a better result.

Answer (score 2):

a work around is to snap every vert from mesh A to mesh B via vert index and use data transfer by close proxy.
please see this post on how to snap it via vert index: [snap objects of same topology together by vertex index](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200997/snap-objects-of-same-topology-together-by-vertex-index/201014#201014)

special thanks to @lemon for comment here and provide solution in above post.