# snap objects of same topology together by vertex index

Tags: modeling

does blender have the function of snapping objects of same topology together by vertex index?
for example, take a simple cube A at origin and duplicate it as cube B, move it aside. now compare vertex index in cube A with cube B and move every vertex in cube A to cube B base on the index number.

it is simple to use modifier such as shrinkwrap and snap to closest vert option, but for more complex mesh, it is often misaligned to different vert on dense parts. hence I wonder if there is a way to do it via vert index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is something about that except Python.

This script will report vertex coordinates of active object to all the selected objects.

**Version 1**

Just give object the same topology:

```
import bpy

def snap_by_vertex_index(obj, target):
    for o, t in zip(obj.data.vertices, target.data.vertices):
        o.co = t.co
        

target = bpy.context.active_object

if target and target.type == 'MESH':
    objects = [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH' and o is not target]
    for o in objects:
        snap_by_vertex_index(o, target)
```

**Version 2**

Or, as suggested @batFINGER in comments, that can be moving vertices to the target:

```
import bpy

def snap_by_vertex_index2(obj, target):
    mat = obj.matrix_world.inverted() @ target.matrix_world
    for o, t in zip(obj.data.vertices, target.data.vertices):
        o.co = mat @ t.co

target = bpy.context.active_object

if target and target.type == 'MESH':
    objects = [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH' and o is not target]
    for o in objects:
        snap_by_vertex_index2(o, target)
```

Comment: Imagine this would require converting target to object space of obj. (and checking vert counts match)

Comment: @batFINGER, I know. But have considered the topology only here. But maybe you're right... just matrices product...

Comment: ok, will add it if you agree

Comment: I think so, going by question otherwise cubes A and B will stay in exactly the same locations

Comment: Yes... or make so a modified mesh comes back to an original (was my though, but again you are often right, so thank you)

Comment: version 1 could also  be `obj.data = target.data` or `target.data.copy()`

Comment: May copy unwanted parts, don't you think?

Comment: If vert counts match its equivalent result isn't it? If  the vert counts don't match...?  Going by q re one a copy of other. If edges and faces differ god knows the result.

Comment: Well... tried that between Suzanne and a cube... poor Suzanne... but was more thinking about loops or others

Comment: WOW~~~ that code works like a charm !!!!! thank you so very much !!!